# Запрос на извлечение объемных данных

Tags: postgresql, sql

Я делаю запрос на извлечение данных из таблицы, в полях которой есть объемные данные. Извлечение нескольких записей занимает очень много времени, и это время растет от количества записей в таблице. К примеру, при наличии 31 записи, запрос занимает 20 секунд. При этом конкретная запись (по id) выбирается очень быстро.

Несколько записей я выбираю так:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (a.id), a.field_1, a.field_2, a.field_3, a.field_4, a.field_5, a.filed_6, ...
FROM table_a a,
     table_b b
WHERE a.field_8 = 'o'
ORDER BY a.field_2 DESC LIMIT 10 ;
```

Сравнение идет по небольшим полям. Как можно ускорить данный запрос?

Проведя эксперимент, я убрал поля с большими данными, все заработало быстрее. Грубо говоря в каждом объекте есть три поля, каждое из которых представляет собой небольшую html страничку. Вроде это не такие уж и большие данные. Тип данных у больших полей `text`, а объявление выглядит так

```
.... field_3 text, field_4 text, ...
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Уберите из запроса таблицу b, она у вас по ходу лишняя. Или покажите запрос полностью, ибо непонятно что вы выбираете. На данный момент у вас получается декартово произведение a*b, которое вы схлопываете distinct'ом до a.
2. Уберите distinct у вас сравниваются записи друг с другом по всем полям, чтоб схлопнуть одинаковые. distinct на редкость вредная функция - затратная и часто запутывающая логику запроса, пользоваться ей необходимо с большой осторожностью.
3. Добавьте индекс по полю (полям), которые участвуют в where.